# Stubbing model attributes in controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, stub

I am finding it very hard to stub certain attributes of a model on a controller test. I want to make sure to stub as little as possible.

---

**EDIT**: I have been demoved of using stubs for such integration. I understood that the stubs won't reach the action call. The correct question would now be:

> How can one use mocks and stubs to simulate a certain state in a Rails controller test?

---

So I've reached something like the following:

### Spec

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe TeamsController do
  let(:team) { FactoryGirl.create :team }

  context "having questions" do
    let(:competition) { FactoryGirl.create :competition }

    it "allows a team to enter a competition" do
      post(:enter_competition, id: team.id, competition_id: competition.id)

      assigns(:enroll).team.should == team
      assigns(:enroll).competition.should == competition
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

### Factories

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do
    name "Ruby team"
  end

  factory :competition, class: Competition do
    name "Competition with questions"

    after_create do |competition|
      competition.
        stub(:questions).
        and_return([ 
          "something"
        ])
    end
  end

  factory :empty_competition, class: Competition do
    name "Competition without questions"
    questions []

    after_create do |competition|
      competition.stub(:questions).and_return []
    end
  end
end
```

### Production code

```rb
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  def enter_competition
    @team = Team.find params[:id]
    @competition = Competition.find params[:competition_id]
    @enroll = @team.enter_competition @competition

    render :nothing => true
  end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  def enter_competition competition
    raise Competition::Closed if competition.questions.empty?

    enroll = Enroll.new team: self, competition: competition
    enroll.save
    enroll
  end
end
```

When I run the test, the `questions` attribute comes as being `nil` and so the test fails in the model when checking for `nil.empty?`.

Why isn't the stub being used so that the state of that message is correctly used? I expected that `@competition.questions` would be `[ "question" ]` but instead I get `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `stub` works on an instance of a Ruby object; it doesn't affect all ActiveRecord objects that represent the same row.

The quickest way to fix your test would be to add this to your test, before the `post`:

```
Competition.stub(:find).and_return(competition)
```

The reason that's necessary is that `Competition.find` will return a fresh `Competition` object that doesn't have `questions` stubbed out, even though it represents the same database row. Stubbing `find` as well means that it will return the same instance of `Competition`, which means the controller will see the stubbed `questions`.

I'd advise against having that stub in your factory, though, because it won't be obvious what's stubbed as a developer using the factory, and because it means you'll never be able to test the real `questions` method, which you'll want to do in the `Competition` unit test as well as any integration tests.

**Long story short**: if you stub out a method on an instance of your model, you also need to stub out `find` for that model (or whatever class method you're using to find it), but it's not a good idea to have such stubs in a factory definition.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `create` on FactoryGirl, it creates database records which you then retrieve back in your controller code. So the instances you get (`@team`, `@competition`) are pure ActiveRecord, without any methods stubbed out.

Personally I would write you test like this (not touching database at all):

```
let(:team) { mock_model(Team) }
let(:competition) { mock_model(Competition) }

before do
  Team.stub(:find) { team }
  Competition.stub(:find) { competition }
end
```

and then in your test something like this:

```
it "should call enter_competition on @team with @competition" do
  team.should_receive(:enter_competition).with(competition)

  post :enter_competition, id: 7, competition_id: 10
```

I don't really understand what your controller is supposed to do or what are you testing for that matter, sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for answering, Art. However, Joe's answer got to the point I was looking for and he also provided an explanation on the way things work.